# VueJS: $router.push not working with query parameters

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js, query-string

In my NuxtJS(v. 2.10.2) application, I have a URL like below where `pid` is a post's id.

> /post?pid=5e4844e34202d6075e593062

This URL works fine and loads the post as per the value passed to the `pid` query parameter. However, user can add new post by clicking `Add Post` button on the application bar that opens a dialog. Once the user clicks add, a request to back-end server is made to save the request. And once successful, user is redirected to the new post using vue router `push` like below

```
.then(data => {
  if (data) {
    this.$router.push({ path: `/post?pid=${data.id}` });
  }
})
```

The problem is, user is not redirected to the new post, only the query parameter `pid` is updated. I suspect VueJS does not acknowledge this as a different URL and hence does nothing.

How to fix this?

Update: As an alternative tried the syntax below but getting the same behavior.

```
this.$router.push({ path: "post", query: { pid: data.id } });
```

Comment: that isn't the way to pass params, try with [this](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html)

Comment: @ChristianCarrillo i tried `this.$router.push({ path: "post", query: { pid: data.id } });`. But getting the same behavior only the query parameter is updated, page is not redirected. Is it working for you?

Comment: try with `name` instead of `path`, previously set `name` property in your routes config

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By changing the approach component data can be updated as per the new query string value. Here is how it can be done.

Rather than trying to push to the same page again with different query string. The query string `pid` itself can be watched for change and on update new data can be fetched and the component data can be updated. In NuxtJS(v. 2.10.2) apps, this can be achieved with `watchQuery`. `watchQuery` is a NuxtJS property which watches changes to a query strings. And once it detects the change, all component methods(asyncData, fetch, validate..) are called. You can read more https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-watchquery/

As for the solution,  pushing to the same page with new query string remains the same.

```
.then(data => {
  if (data) {
    this.$router.push({ name: 'post', query: { pid: data.id } });
  }
})
```

However, on the page.vue, where the data is fetched from the server. We need to add `watchQuery` property.

```
watchQuery: ["pid"],
async asyncData(context) {
  let response = await context.$axios.$get(
    `http://localhost:8080/find/id/${context.route.query.pid}`
  );
  return { postData: response };
},
data: () => ({
  postData: null
})
```

Now, everytime the query string `pid` will change `asyncData` will be called. And that is it. An easy fix to updating component data when the query string value change.

Comment: this is very simple put like in routes array 
{
        path: "/add-party",
        name: "add-party",
        component:AddParty
    },
and navigate using this
 this.$router.push({ name: 'add-party', query: { id: Id } });

Answer (score 8):

Say you have a component `post.vue` which is mapped with `/post` URL.

Now if you redirect the user to `/post?pid=13`, the `post.vue` **component won't mount again if it's already mounted** ie. when you are already at `/post` or `/post?pid=12`.

[1] In this case, you can put a `watch` on the `route` to know if the route has been changed.

```
watch: {
 '$route.path': {
   handler (oldUrl, newUrl) {
     let PID = this.$route.query.pid
     // fetch data for this PID from the server.
     // ...
  }
 }
}
```

OR

[2] If the component `post.vue` is mapped with some route say `/post`.

You can also use the lifecycle -> `beforeRouteUpdate` provided by `vue-router`

```
beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
  let PID = to.query.pid
  // fetch data for this PID from the server.
  // ...
  next()
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. Want to add here that if you open an email component (say) from clicking on notification bell icon header comp (sey) clicking on a different notification will not refresh the already open email component. Hence used watch as you suggested with a difference. In my case as the method to refresh is in a different component, with its corresponding html etc, used an eventBus to emit a flag which then reached the mounted of email component and refreshed API.

Comment: @shivam is it okay to just call router.go () ?

Answer (score 1):

try this solution

```
.then(data => {
  if (data) {
    this.$router.push({ name: 'post', query: { pid: data.id } });
  }
})
```

hints:

```
// with query, resulting in /register?plan=private
router.push({ path: 'register', query: { plan: 'private' } })
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody was looking for this:

Query parameters specified as a string do not work when passed to a `path` parameter:
`router.push({path: 'route?query=params'})`

When you want you use them as a string, just pass the whole string as an argument, like so: `router.push('route?query=params')`

It'll then be automagically picked by router and navigation will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Use **watchQuery** property (https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/components-glossary/pages-watchquery)

```
export default {
  watchQuery: true,
  data: () => ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

try this :

```
.then(data => {
  if (data) {
    this.$router.push('/post?pid=' + data.id);
  }
})
```

hope it works!!!

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: This is actually what I was looking for!